# Enable HTML5 Javadoc in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc, java-10

We have upgraded a Java project to JDK 10. When running the build script, Javadoc outputs a warning:

```
javadoc: warning - You have not specified the version of HTML to use.
The default is currently HTML 4.01, but this will change to HTML5
in a future release. To suppress this warning, please specify the
version of HTML used in your documentation comments and to be
generated by this doclet, using the -html4 or -html5 options.
```

For building the project, we use *gradle*. How can we specify HTML 5 (`-html5`) in gradle?

So far, the *javadoc* section of our `build.gradle` file is rather simple:

```
javadoc {
    include 'com/company/project/pkg/*'
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's straightforward with `options.addBooleanOption`:

```
javadoc {
    include 'com/company/project/pkg/*'
    options.addBooleanOption('html5', true)
}
```

Note that you have to use `addBooleanOption` and not `addStringOption`. The latter one does not work without a value (such as `""`) and then produces an invalid command line.

Answer (score 5):

When getting the error mentioned above for you maven project, you can put the following snippet in your `pom.xml`:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${javadocplugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <additionalOptions>-html5</additionalOptions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: How does maven config have anything to do with gradle config?

Comment: Hi @trappski. I was getting exactly the same error message from above for my Maven project. When I googled for the error message, this stackoverflow post was one of the first that appeared in the search results, and it took me quite a while coming up with the solution above for Maven. I was hoping to save some time for people having the same issue and which are directed to this post when searching for a solution.