# Font tag not supported in javadoc

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, javadoc, gradle-plugin

Im using Java 16 and build my project with gradle.
I want to use `gradle javadoc` to generate a javadoc from my comments. But when i executed the command, I got following error:

> error: tag not supported in the generated HTML version: font

The class comment this error refers to looks something like this:

```
/**
 * Websocket to handle changes.<br>
 * <font color="red">A RED COMMENT </font><br>
 * <font color="orange">AN ORANGE COMMENT</font>
 **/
```

Intellij shows me the comment exactly like i want, but I get this error while generating javadoc.

I did not configure the javadoc generation in the build.gradle or anywhere else. The only solution i found was to set the html version inside the javadoc step in build.gradle ([Enable HTML5 Javadoc in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222047/enable-html5-javadoc-in-gradle)) but this didn't change anything

Any idea?

Comment: Wrong:  `<font color="red">`  Right:  `<span style="color: red">`  As aled pointed out, `<font>` is no longer a valid HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probable that your version of Javadoc is using already using HTML5 which deprecated the `<font>` tag. You should use CSS for styling.